# VueJS return loop data values through a node plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm trying to create an Vue app which takes one key color and creates a color palette from the key color. 2 colors lighter and 2 colors darker. I have an input field where you enter a hex code and it will then generate the other 4 colours. I'm using the library [chroma.js](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/) to generate darker/brighter colors and the syntax looks like this:

`chroma('red').darken(.4)`

And this is the input field

```
<input class="w-100 pv3 pl4 input-reset ba b--black-20" @keyup="getColor(colorValue)" v-model="colorValue" placeholder="0AD674" >
```

This is my for loop

```
<li v-for="item in items">
  {{ item.colorProperty }}
  {{ item.intensity }}
  {{ colorValue }}
</li>
```

And my data inside the Vue instance.

```
data () {
    return {
      colorValue: '4e35e1',
      items: [
            {
              intensity: 3,
              colorProperty: 'darken'
            },
            {
              intensity: 1,
              colorProperty: 'darken'
            },
            {
              intensity: 0,
              colorProperty: ''
            },
            {
              intensity: 1,
              colorProperty: 'brighten'
            },
            {
              intensity: 3,
              colorProperty: 'brighten'
            }
          ],
    }
}
```

All of this generates something like

```
3 darken 4e35e1
1 darken 4e35e1
0 4e35e1
1 brighten 4e35e1
3 brighten 4e35e1
```

Which is cool but ideally **I would use the data values to feed the Chroma.js syntax like**

```
transformColor: function(value, property, intensity) {
   return chroma(value).property(intensity)
}
```

But obviously that doesn't work. What's the best way to achieve this?

I realise this is a open ended question. But I have had troubles figuring out whether I should use a filter or a component or a computed function. I tried most things but none of them would work. I come from a jQuery background so this new data-centric approach is proving to be difficult to wrap my head around. I'm grateful for any pointers!

Solved by using `map()`

```
 computed: {
    colors() {
      return this.items.map((item) => {
        var colorHex = chroma(this.colorValue)[item.colorProperty](item.intensity).toString();
        var colorName = _.kebabCase(namer(colorHex).ntc[0].name);
        return {colorHex, colorName}
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's the desired result, the actual colors instead of the parameters that would generate that color? You can dynamically access object properties through bracket notation `return chroma(value)[property](intensity)`

Comment: Correct the desired result is a hex value that has been transformed by the chroma plugin. Thanks for the bracket notation code, that brings me a bit closer to what I want to do

Comment: I see [you edited the question Aug 17 '17 at 12:19](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45718522/revisions) with the addition “_Solved by using `map()`_” followed by a code block- if that is a solution you should add an answer to the question instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `map()`

```
computed: {
    colors() {
      return this.items.map((item) => {
        var colorHex = chroma(this.colorValue)[item.colorProperty](item.intensity).toString();
        var colorName = _.kebabCase(namer(colorHex).ntc[0].name);
        return {colorHex, colorName}
      });
    }
  }
```